# Set dpi using imwrite in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm wondering whether there is a way to set `dpi` to 600 using `imwrite`.  I'm trying to write text to an image which I will later need to OCR.

I'm also wondering if there's a particular image format that is best for OCR - disk space and processing time are not a primary constraints (yet).  I'm using `python 3.4` and `opencv2` - would be very appreciative if anyone has any tips for how to increase the dpi.

Comment: I'm still just reading docs to see what I'm not understanding about imwrite.  It seems there would be a set of params to define image quality and compression, etc, but I don't see that.  Is this something that has to get defined as a part of the np.array?

Comment: No you can't (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860969/change-dpi-of-an-image-in-opencv). How do you expect it to benefit OCR, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the link - I assumed my issue was dpi.  Here's my issue - when I try to ocr a doc (plain black arial font on white), I get 99% accuracy.  However, the text on that page isn't delimeted.  So I recognize each word, add a delimeter, write it back at the same x,y to a new blank bg, then ocr it again (viola, didn't have to spend time on table detection).  However, the accuracy of the second pass ocr is like 75%.  Right now my suspects are the Hershey font versus Arial,  cv2.imwrite adding artifacts around the letters or something else with compression or resolution of the image.

Comment: Do you save your intermediate results? Do you use jpeg format for that?

Comment: I switched to png and the output improved significantly but still not as good as ocr on the source image.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57555123/2836621