# imageio.imread(): Retains the original grayscale values when reading a png file

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imageio

I would like to process a 12-bit grayscale image saved in png format. A monochromatic 12-bit camera was used as the signal source. The image file was created with NI Vision `IMAQ Write File2.vi`. The maximum pixel value is 419 counts. When I load the image with Python3 `imageio-2.32.0` `imageio.imread("testimagefile")`, it seems that the image is scaled automatically, the maximum value is now 55019 counts. How can I keep the original grayscale value?

Comment: Are you sure it’s not saved scaled?

Comment: maybe `imageio.imread("testimagefile", pilmode="I;12")` would give a different result?

Comment: [mre] please, i.e. the file, or *a* file that shows this

Comment: @CrisLuengo: As far i stay in LabVIEW-Universe everything is fine. However, to be honest I don't know, that the VI (LabVIEW Function) does under the hut.

@Marijn: I get `ValueError: conversion from L to I;12 not supported` if I try to do this.

@ChristophRackwitz: You can see the image here: https://cloud.uni-jena.de/s/iqxJrDY28DJ2qjN

Answer (score 2):

I finally got an answer on the [NI-Forum](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/How-do-you-load-signed-16-bit-png-file-outside-of-labVIEW/m-p/4253919#M54066). Many thanks to Andrew Dmitriev.

> The NI's 16 bit PNG images stored together with sBIT. It means that the pixel's values are shifted to the highest bit (this is a part of PNG Standard, but most libraries aren't aware about this).
> Refer to http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.sBIT
>
> In additional, the Offset for signed representation stored in first
> two bytes of the scAl chunk. So, all what you need - just read "RAW"
> png data, then perform shift according sBIT value, then subtract
> offset taken from scAl chunk. That is all (if you want to get things
> done without "extra" DLL). Attached example for both I16 and U16
> images.
>
> By the way - there is a bug in PNG encoder from NI. Instead of logical
> shifting they performing rotating (in some strange form), so the less
> significant bits which supposed to be zeroes - are not zeroes, as
> result we have these strange values mentioned above (for example, when
> the range 0...1000 turned to 0...64062. It should be 0...64000
> instead). But this is not a big problem, because these bits goes away
> after shifting back.
>
> Also in Manual it wrongly stated that Use Bit Depth input is
> applicable to signed images only. On signed images this control will
> cut off negative values, but on unsigned images (when used together
> IMAQ Image Bit Depth) this will allow to save "native" 16 bit values,
> so the image can be opened in third-party libraries without
> conversion.

Here is the code using openCV by [dgagnon05](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/How-do-you-load-signed-16-bit-png-file-outside-of-labVIEW/td-p/4247192/page/2):

```
import cv2
import struct
import binascii
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def __getSBit(bytes):
    bytes = bytes[8:]
    sBit = 0
    while bytes:
        length = struct.unpack('>I', bytes[:4])[0]
        bytes = bytes[4:]
        chunk_type = bytes[:4]
        bytes = bytes[4:]
        chunk_data = bytes[:length]
        bytes = bytes[length:]
        if chunk_type == b'sBIT':
            sBit = int.from_bytes(chunk_data, "big")
            break
        bytes = bytes[4:]
    return sBit

def __getOffset(bytes):
    bytes = bytes[8:]
    Offset = 0
    sBit = 0
    while bytes:
        length = struct.unpack('>I', bytes[:4])[0]
        bytes = bytes[4:]
        chunk_type = bytes[:4]
        bytes = bytes[4:]
        chunk_data = bytes[:length]
        bytes = bytes[length:]
        if chunk_type == b'scAl':
            chunk_data_part = chunk_data[:2]
            Offset = 65536 - int.from_bytes(chunk_data_part, "big")
            break
        bytes = bytes[4:]
    return Offset

def getSigBits(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        bytes = f.read()
    return __getSBit(bytes)

def getOffset(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        bytes = f.read()
    return __getOffset(bytes)

def shift_offset(image_src, shift, offset):
    height, width = image_src.shape
    counter=0;
    if shift<16:
        temp=np.zeros(image_src.shape,dtype=np.int16)
        temp=(image_src>> shift).astype(np.int16)
        temp=temp-offset
        return temp


def load_lv_i16(file_path):
    offset=getOffset(file_path)
    sigbits=getSigBits(file_path)
    image_src=cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    shift=16-sigbits
    image=shift_offset(image_src,shift,offset)
    return image

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_path=r"LabVIEW_created_12bit_grayscale.png"
    image=load_lv_i16(file_path)
```

---------- UPDATE ----------

After answer from @Mark Setchell the better solution may be:

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

file_path = 'LabVIEW_created_12bit_grayscale.png'
# Load PNG as bytes and find "sBIT" and NI-Vision "scAl" chunk
png = Path(file_path).read_bytes()
sBIToffset = png.find(b'sBIT')
scAl = png.find(b'scAl') # scAl is a constant offset

if sBIToffset>0:
    # 4 bytes before "sBIT" tell us how many values there are - could be 1-4 values
    nValues = int.from_bytes(png[sBIToffset-4:sBIToffset], byteorder="big")
    values  = list(png[sBIToffset+4:sBIToffset+4+nValues])

offset=0
if scAl>0:
    offset = 65536 - int.from_bytes(png[scAl+4:scAl+6], "big")

if len(values)==1:
    image_src=cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    shift = 16-values[0]
    if shift<16:
        temp=np.zeros(image_src.shape,dtype=np.int16)
        image=(image_src>> shift).astype(np.int16)
    if offset>0:
        image=image-offset
    print(cv2.minMaxLoc(image))
else:
    print("Seems not to be a greyscale image!")
```

Comment: 20.11.2023: added also check for constant offset in `scAl` chunk.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path

# Load PNG as bytes
png = Path('image.png').read_bytes()

# Find "sBIT" chunk
sBIToffset = png.find(b'sBIT')
if sBIToffset:
    # 4 bytes before "sBIT" tell us how many values there are - could be 1-4 values
    nValues = int.from_bytes(png[sBIToffset-4:sBIToffset], byteorder="big")
    values  = list(png[sBIToffset+4:sBIToffset+4+nValues])
    print(f'Found sBIT chunk at offset: {sBIToffset} with value(s): {values}')

# Find "scAl" chunk
scAloffset = png.find(b'scAl')
if scAloffset:
    scAl = int.from_bytes(png[scAloffset+4:scAloffset+6], byteorder="big")
    value = 65536 - scAl
    print(f'Found scAl chunk at offset: {scAloffset} with value: {value}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
Found sBIT chunk at offset: 37 with value(s): [11]
Found scAl chunk at offset: 64 with value: 1000
```

---

**Original Answer**

This is an alternative to the (IMHO really rather poor) implementation of finding the `sBIT` chunk and extracting the scale factors.

PNG chunks look like this:

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG)

The `sBIT` chunk looks like this in hex:

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 056c 0000 040e 1000 0000 003a b9f2  ...l.........:..
00000020: 5200 0000 0173 4249 5409 910d 6b0f 0000  R....sBIT...k...
```

In hex, the `73 42 49 54` (in the middle of the third line) represents `sBIT`, so the length is the 4 bytes before that, i.e. `00 00 00 01` and that means there is 1 value in the chunk - which is to be expected in a greyscale image. There might be up to 4 values depending on the image type (grey, grey+alpha, RGB, RGBA). That means only 1 byte is used in this image. That byte is `09` meaning the value is 9.

As such, you can more simply extract the sBIT(s) like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path

# Load PNG as bytes and find "sBIT" chunk
png = Path('120130.png').read_bytes()
sBIToffset = png.find(b'sBIT')
if sBIToffset:
    # 4 bytes before "sBIT" tell us how many values there are - could be 1-4 values
    nValues = int.from_bytes(png[sBIToffset-4:sBIToffset], byteorder="big")
    values  = list(png[sBIToffset+4:sBIToffset+4+nValues])
    print(f'Found sBIT chunk at offset: {sBIToffset} with value(s): {values}')
```

---

Note that you can detect the presence of rare chunks in a PNG file using:

```
pngcheck -vv SOMEIMAGE.PNG
```

You can also `grep` them:

```
grep sBIT SOMEIMAGE.PNG
```

---

I describe the other implementation as *"rather poor"* because it spends its time shuffling the entire content of the file around in memory and doesn't handle multiple significant bits for multi-channel images - it also reads the file twice and....

I am aware of that my code is also imperfect insofar as it doesn't check the CRC, but I didn't want to muddy the code. If checking the CRC is important, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57555123/2836621) shows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much! On NI forum is mentioned a "scAl" chunk to find and subtract an offset from image. But I can't find anything about it in the PNG specs. "sCAL" seems to have a different meaning. If an image is not monochrome, the  `len(values)!=1`, correct?

Comment: `sCAL` is a v1.2 addition I think. It should have no bearing on the numerical pixel values, it is related to the physical size of he object being imaged - kind of like `dpi` but going the other way. See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/register/pngext-1.4.0-pdg.html

Comment: Also, I didn't find a `sCAL` or `seal` in the image you shared which is why I didn't worry about decoding it.

Comment: Yes, I am expecting `len(values) == 1` for a greyscale image such as yours.

Comment: I got the answer [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/How-do-you-load-signed-16-bit-png-file-outside-of-labVIEW/m-p/4340215/highlight/true#M54421).
`scAI` (with a capital **i**) is by definition a private chunk (beginns with two lower letters). It appears when NI PNGs have negative values in the image, otherwise not.

Comment: Cool - thank you for sharing back with the community. I presume you can copy and modify easily enough my code for `sBIT` if you need the `scAI` chunk.

Comment: Sorry, it's really confusing `scAl`, with small **L** ...

Comment: I ran `pngcheck -vv YOURIMAGE.PNG` and there is an `sBIT` chunk but no `scAl` or `scAL` or even similar found. I then ran `grep -Ei "SCAL|SCAI" YOURIMAGE.PNG`and nothing was found.

Comment: [Here](https://cloud.uni-jena.de/s/jjA7Xt268CJzf5f) You can find a image wich a `scAl` chunk. Only NI-Vision images with negative values have one.

Comment: That one also doesn't have any `scXX` chunks. You can check for yourself using the commands I gave above. You can also load it into https://hexed.it and look at the start of the file - you will see `PNG`, `IHDR`, `sBIT`, some text and then the data `IDAT` but no `scXX`

Comment: Sorry, I have overwritten the file by incident. Now it has one `scAl` chunk.

Comment: I have updated my code - please have another look.