# How to keep DPI of sliced image the same as the original image in python cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, dpi

```
import cv2
img = 'image.jpg' # 300dpi
img = cv2.imread(img)
sliced_img = img(0:200,0:100)
cv2.imwrite('sliced.jpg',sliced_img) # 96dpi
```

Is there any parameter to specify the dpi of sliced image?
I want to keep the original dpi instead of changing the dpi...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to increase dpi with opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503960/how-to-increase-dpi-with-opencv)

Comment: Actually, my other answer here is more helpful in changing the dpi... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57555123/2836621

Comment: I have seen your answer , but I want to keep the original dpi instead of changing the dpi ...

Comment: Ok, so read the dpi of the original image and set it in the output image. You can copy forward the whole APP0 segment if JPEG, see https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/ I mean copy the first 18 bytes of your input file and replace the first 18 bytes of your output file with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quickly hacked together idea of how you could copy forward the `APP0` segment (which contains the dpi) from your input image to your output image. There is some pretty reasonable description of the anatomy of a JPEG [here](https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/2017-01-31_jpeg/).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input image with 300 dpi
im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

# Grab its APP0 segment (with dpi) in first 18 bytes
with open('image.jpg', 'rb') as jpeg:
    APP0 = jpeg.read(18)

# Process image ...

# Write result as JPEG to in-memory buffer
_, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", im)

# Copy forward APP0 from original image
buffer[:18] = np.frombuffer(APP0, np.uint8)

# Write JPEG to disk with copied forward APP0
with open('result.jpg', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(buffer)
```

Check file with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool result.jpg

ExifTool Version Number         : 12.30
File Name                       : result.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 18 KiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:12:21 15:51:14+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:12:21 15:51:23+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:12:21 15:51:22+00:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : inches
X Resolution                    : 300        <--- DPI HERE
Y Resolution                    : 300        <--- DPI HERE
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 480
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 640x480
Megapixels                      : 0.307
```

---

It is probably more professional to use [PyExifTool](https://sylikc.github.io/pyexiftool/), if you don't mind adding another dependency to your project.

```
import exiftool

# Get dpi from input image
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    res = et.get_tags(['JFIF:XResolution','JFIF:YResolution'], 'image.jpg')
```

That gives this as the value for `res`:

```
 {'SourceFile': 'image.jpg', 'JFIF:XResolution': 300, 'JFIF:YResolution': 300}
```

And you can set the dpi on the output file to 10 or whatever you want like this:

```
# You can probably omit the full path to exiftool if it is on your PATH
with exiftool.ExifTool("/opt/homebrew/bin/exiftool") as et:
    et.execute(b"-JFIF:XResolution=10", b"result.jpg")
    et.execute(b"-JFIF:YResolution=10", b"result.jpg")
```