# How to extract metadata using PIL.exiftags?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, metadata, exif

I've just been following guides that show the same steps to extracting GPS data from an image. Most of them use the following dictionary definition.

```
[exif definition][1] 
exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v 
    for k, v in pil_img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}
```

However, I keep getting AttributeError: _getexif and I have no idea how to fix this. I am new to python. I've ensured the image I'm using has GPS information but I still can't access any of the metadata. Here is the full code so far: Note I am using cv2 to practice converting as this will be applicable to my project
[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68rGE.png)

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
img = cv2.imread("keyboard.png")
convert = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_img = Image.fromarray(convert)

exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v 
    for k, v in pil_img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}
```

Additionally if I try to call exif like I saw in a tutorial, I get the following error: [exif not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPi9n.png)

```
exif : The term 'exif' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ exif
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (exif:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Please don't take screenshots of your code and errors. Instead you should include them in your question as text. That way it is easier for people to work with it. [ask]

Comment: Or would you want a solution to also be served in screenshots only?

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time posting on here. Didn't know I could easily include code in text.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


pil_img = Image.open("img.jpg")
exif_info = pil_img._getexif()
exif = {TAGS.get(k, k): v for k, v in exif_info.items()}
print(exif)
```

Please note:

- It is unlikely that the EXIF data persists if you read the image with opencv, convert the colour space and reimport the binary image data to PIL.
- I don't have png images with exif data. This was tested with jpg only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot possibly work with **OpenCV** in that fashion.

When you do:

```
img = cv2.imread("keyboard.png")
```

you get back a Numpy array of just the **pixels** in your variable `img` - and that's all, nothing else, no EXIF, no IPTC, no ICC profile, absolutely zero metadata. **OpenCV** is only interested in computer vision, not cataloguing, indexing, sorting, managing images by where they were taken or when or by whom or what.

You can use **PIL** to read metadata, or `exiftool` or its Python bindings - example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438206/2836621).