# processing image tags, kill subprocess after finishes with data and start a new one

Tags: image-processing, subprocess, stdout

loop over <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

Hi,

I ran a software for processing image tags as subprocess (in Python). When looping over tags, app expects to press "Enter" button manually in order to execute the code after. That's how it is for every single tag (iteration). Tags are stored in process.stdout. Is it possible for subprocess to be killed automatically after every iteration when app executes code after it (for example putting data into Excel or something else)?

```
import os
import subprocess


exifToolPath = r'C:\some path\exiftool(-k).exe' # subprocess starting, external software


folder_dir = r"C:\some path" # path where images are stored


for file in os.listdir(folder_dir):

    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder_dir, file))

    # check if the image ends with png, JPG, jpeg or jpg
    if (file.endswith(".png")) or file.endswith(".JPG")\
            or file.endswith(".jpeg") or file.endswith(".jpg"):

        process = subprocess.Popen([exifToolPath, path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                   universal_newlines=True, shell=False)

        infoDict = {}

        
        for tag in process.stdout:
            
            line = tag.strip().split(':')
            infoDict[line[0].strip()] = line[-1].strip()

        # here app expects manually to press Enter in order to continue 
        for k, v in infoDict.items():
            print(k, ':', v)
```

Comment: Your question is missing the bigger picture. All I can tell is that you want to start a new `exiftool` process for each of lots of images (seems dubious and inefficient) and then put something in Excel and kill a subprocess? Please click [edit] and try to improve your question. Why are you using subprocess anyway - why not use a Python binding to `exiftool`, or use **PIL** to get the tags?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to subprocessing and that was my only idea :). How to use a Python binding to exiftool? PIL does not give me every tag from an image

Comment: See last part of this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70438206/2836621